# Обращение к полям массива объектов

Tags: c++

Я решил сделать свою простенькую игру. Для "процедурной отрисовки текстуры" хотел создать матрицы цветов и заполнить их, попытался сделать это напрямую:

```
struct blockColor{
int r;
int g;
int b;
blockColor()
{
    r = 0;
    g = 0;
    b = 0;
};
};

blockColor brickColorMap[8][8];
brickColorMap[8][8].r = 
{
 {54, 54, 54, 54, 64, 54, 54, 54},
 {54, 54, 54, 54, 64, 54, 54, 54},
 {64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64},
 {54, 64, 54, 54, 54, 54, 64, 54},
 {54, 64, 54, 54, 54, 54, 64, 54},
 {64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64},
 {54, 54, 54, 64, 54, 54, 54, 54},
 {54, 54, 54, 64, 54, 54, 54, 54}
};
```

Компилятор, естественно, выдает ошибку. Как было бы правильно заполнить такую матрицу полей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я бы предложил просто функцию инициализации сделать. Т.е. инициализировать матрицу на старте программы из другого массива. Как-то так например:

```
struct blockColor{
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
    blockColor()
    {
        r = 0;
        g = 0;
        b = 0;
    };
};

blockColor brickColorMap[8][8];

int r_color[8][8] =
{
    { 54, 54, 54, 54, 64, 54, 54, 54 },
    { 54, 54, 54, 54, 64, 54, 54, 54 },
    { 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64 },
    { 54, 64, 54, 54, 54, 54, 64, 54 },
    { 54, 64, 54, 54, 54, 54, 64, 54 },
    { 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64 },
    { 54, 54, 54, 64, 54, 54, 54, 54 },
    { 54, 54, 54, 64, 54, 54, 54, 54 }
};

int g_color[8][8] =
{
    // ...
};

int b_color[8][8] =
{
    // ...
};

void initColor(int blockColor::*member, int data[8][8])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
            brickColorMap[i][j].*member = data[i][j];
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    initColor(&blockColor::r, r_color);
    initColor(&blockColor::g, g_color);
    initColor(&blockColor::b, b_color);

    return 0;
}
```

Используется указатель на член структуры в качестве параметра, чтобы можно было повторно использовать одну функцию initColor для всех 3 цветов.

Answer (score 3):

В С++11 появился **initializer_list**. Можно сделать так:

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct blockColor{
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
    blockColor()
    {
        r = 0;
        g = 0;
        b = 0;
    };
    blockColor(std::initializer_list<int> init)
    {
        const int* it = init.begin();
        r = *it++;
        g = *it++;
        b = *it;
    };
};

blockColor brickColorMap[3][2] =
{
    { { 54, 54, 54 }, { 54, 54, 54 } },
    { { 64, 64, 64 }, { 64, 64, 64 } },
    { { 54, 64, 54 }, { 54, 54, 54 } }
};
```

Comment: То есть таким образом можно в одном двумерном массиве задать сразу все три поля (r, g, b) вместо создания трех матриц отдельно для каждого цвета?
Попробовал ваш код - не компилируется - "Инициализация объектов типа "blockColor" с помощью выражения {....} не допускается.
Работаю в MVS2010

Comment: 2010 не поддерживает C++11

Comment: Но ведь это же ужасно, право слово. Зачем здесь `initializer_list`, он совсем для других целей...

Comment: Эм.. А зачем initializer list, если присваивание структур по полям работает с древнейших времён?

Comment: Вариант предложенный @Qwertiy действительно лучше и работает в VS2010.

Answer (score 2):

http://codepad.org/9Uxqmnn3

```
struct blockColor {
    int r, g, b;
};

blockColor brickColorMap[3][2] = {
    { { 54, 54, 54 }, { 54, 54, 54 } },
    { { 64, 64, 64 }, { 64, 64, 64 } },
    { { 54, 64, 54 }, { 54, 54, 54 } }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно просто добавить конструктор для всех 3-х цветов и использовать его:

```
struct blockColor{
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
    blockColor()
    {
        r = 0;
        g = 0;
        b = 0;
    }

    blockColor(int r, int g, int b)
    {
        this->r = r;
        this->g = g;
        this->b = b;
    }
};

blockColor brickColorMap[2][2] =
{
    {blockColor(54, 54, 54), blockColor(55, 55, 55)},
    {blockColor(56, 56, 56), blockColor(57, 57, 57)},
};
```

Инициализация в стиле современного C++, который MSVC2010 поддерживает не полностью(в частности такая инициализация там работать не будет):

```
blockColor brickColorMap[2][2] =
{
    {{54, 54, 54}, {55, 55, 55}},
    {{56, 56, 56}, {57, 57, 57}},
};
```

Comment: Если снести конструкторы, то, вероятно, будет. По крайней мере, g++ плюётся именно в случае с присутствующим конструктором.

Comment: @Qwertiy, тут не на что плеваться. Если убрать конструкторы, то произойдёт aggregation initialization, которая не использует конструктор. Это вполне себе метод, просто я aggregation initialization не приветствую.

Comment: Да, я про aggregation initializer. При конструкторе он не компилируется: http://codepad.org/9Uxqmnn3 и http://codepad.org/sPoMOYN4

Comment: @Qwertiy, не знаю, что там за компилятор и флаги на этом codepad, вот Вам [ideone](http://ideone.com/uChKb0)

Comment: Забавно. Там точно есть трактовка предупреждений как ошибок. Что ещё - не знаю. Наверное, какая-то из аналитических проверок сработала.

Comment: Кстати, после конструкторов точки с запятой лишние. http://ideone.com/OlkpeC

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага, спасибо, убрал.

Comment: Я смотрю, их все кроме меня из вопроса скопипастили)))